# Calculate the minimum value of $T = 3x + 2y$ with positives $x$ and $y$ satisfying $\log_3\frac{xy + 2}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{3^x + 3x^2 + 1}{3^x + xy}$.

Tags: algorithms

> Consider two positives $x$ and $y$ such that $\log_3\dfrac{xy + 2}{x^2 + 1} = \dfrac{3^x + 3x^2 + 1}{3^x + xy}$. Calculate the minimum value of $T = 3x + 2y$.

We have that $$\begin{aligned} \log_3\dfrac{xy + 2}{x^2 + 1} = \dfrac{3^x + 3x^2 + 1}{3^x + xy} \iff \log_3(xy + 2) - \log_3(3x^2 + 3) = \dfrac{(3x^2 + 3) - (xy + 2)}{3^x + xy} \end{aligned}$$

I don't know how to notate this, but let $z$ be a variable and $f(x), g(x)$ be functions such that $g(f(x), z) = f(x) + (3^z + yz)\log_3f(x)$, which means that $g(xy + 2, x) = g(3x^2 + 3, x)$ and $$\dfrac{\mathrm dg(f(x), x)}{\mathrm dx} = f'(x) + \dfrac{(3^x\ln 3 + y)\ln f(x)}{\ln 3} + \dfrac{(3^x + xy)f'(x)}{\ln 3f(x)}$$

Entering the equation $g'(x) = 0$ into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%20y%20f%27%28x%29%20%2B%203%5Ex%20f%27%28x%29%20%2B%20log%283%29%20f%28x%29%20f%27%28x%29%20%2B%20y%20f%28x%29%20log%28f%28x%29%29%20%2B%203%5Ex%20log%283%29%20f%28x%29%20log%28f%28x%29%29%20%3D%200), function $f(x)$ can be written in the form of $$f(x) = \dfrac{3^x + xy}{\ln 3}W\left(\dfrac{\ln 3}{(3^x + xy)e^{(3^x + xy)/c}}\right)$$ with $c$ being a constant and $W(z)$ being the product log function/Lambert $W$ function. Now, I don't know about this function, so I'd consider this a dead end.

I do have a hunch that $xy + 2 = 3x^2 + 3$, I just don't know how to prove it.

How about continuing from this point on? It can be implied that $y = \dfrac{3x^2 + 1}{x}$, which makes $T$ equal to $3x + \dfrac{2(3x^2 + 1)}{x}$. From there, $T' = 0 \iff 9 - \dfrac{2}{x^2} = 0 \iff x = \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{3}$

Drawing the table of variations for $T$, it can be seen that $\min T = 9 \cdot \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{3} + \dfrac{2}{\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{3}} = 6\sqrt{2}$.

Now, if I could just prove that $xy + 2 = 3x^2 + 3$, it would be fantastic. So I turn to your support.

As always, thanks for reading, (and even more if you could help~)

Comment: I am stuck but I think that I should change the problem replacing $y$ by $\frac{z-2}{x}$ with $z>2$

Comment: If $y = \dfrac{3x^2 + 1}{x}$, the constraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the auxiliary Lagrangian function
$$\mathscr L=3x+2y-\lambda\left(\log_3\frac{xy+2}{x^2+1}-\frac{3^x+3x^2+1}{3^x+xy}\right)+\mu_1x+\mu_2y.$$

The first order conditions for a minimum (see [KKT multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)) are

\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial x}&=0\\
 \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial y}&=0\\
 \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial \lambda}&=0\\
 \mu_1x&=0\\
 \mu_2y&=0
\end{align}

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: No, I didn't @ClaudeLeibovici Does it crash?

Comment: I tried ! This would lead to a mega monster. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Given that my answer is not helpful, should I delete it? I'm unsure about the etiquette...

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your answer. If the work was numerical, it would even be perfect. Numrically, the problem is very simple. Leave it

Comment: I thought it was starting to get annoying, so I didn't add a paragraph at the start of the problem unlike I had with the previous few. It basically says that this problem is meant to be done under a time constraint and only with a calculator. Numerical solutions aren't what I'm looking for, but feel free to keep them, I'd appreciate it~